# Elastic search : Connection Refused

Tags: elasticsearch

Up until 3 days ago my elastic search(local installation) was working perfectly fine.

Today it stopped working given as connection error.

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=9200): Max retries exceeded with url:
```

I tried the following options too.

```
curl -XGET http://127.0.0.1:9200
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 9200: Connection refused
```

I tried running it manually using the below code and received the following error.

```
cd /usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/2.4.0

ElasticsearchException[failed to read [id:206, legacy:false, file:/usr/local/var/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_sam/nodes/0/_state/global-206.st]]; nested: IOException[failed to read [id:206, legacy:false, file:/usr/local/var/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_sam/nodes/0/_state/global-206.st]]; nested: CorruptStateException[Format version is not supported (resource SimpleFSIndexInput(path="/usr/local/var/elasticsearch/elasticsearch_sam/nodes/0/_state/global-206.st"))
```

The Elastic search version I am using is 2.4.0 and java version is java version "1.8.0_101" and I am running a MAC system

I have all my data stored in Elastic search without any back up.

I'd be glad if anybody could help me with the situation

Thanks

Comment: If you open http://127.0.0.1:9200 in browser what do you see?

Comment: because problem seems to be that ES is not started. Check logs

Comment: It says "Safari Cant connect to the server"

Comment: try to restart ES, and go to logs folder see what is going there?

Comment: I am not sure, I didn't have to manually start elastic search earlier. I ran the bin/elasticsearch command going to the installation directory "cd /usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/2.4.0". It gives the same error 'ElasticsearchException[failed to read [id:206,..........'

Comment: Also by checking the log file .. I see no log registered for today, The last registered log is for 22nd january. When I last operated Elastic Search

Answer (score 1):

You get a [CorruptStateException](http://javadoc.kyubu.de/elasticsearch/HEAD/org/elasticsearch/gateway/CorruptStateException.html) which means Elasticsearch detects an inconsistency in one of it's persistent states.

Basically just identify the broken shard `curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_cluster/state?pretty=true > foo.json`
The shard(s) will have "INITIALIZING" status and will have their node id 
associated, which will let you know where is the blocked shard. 
If you're using one replica, and the other shard is efficiently started, 
you can just remove the directory containing the broken shard (the one you 
executer the check index thing) and it should rebuild itself based on the 
other, uncorrupted shard (from another node).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case whoever faced the issue: `Guice Exception: ElasticsearchException[failed to read...` with `Likely root cause: org.elasticsearch.gateway.CorruptStateException: Format version is not supported`. Simply remove any folder/files in `/usr/local/var/elasticsearch` and then the service should be back up and running.

Hope this helps.